# Stored procedure returns no records when datetime filters are NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Consider this stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getclients]
    @FromDate datetime, @ToDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM CM.Clients
    --If both dates are not NULL then also check PurchaseDate to be between them
    WHERE
        (@FromDate IS NOT NULL AND @ToDate IS NOT NULL 
         AND Clients.PurchaseDate >= @FromDate 
         AND Clients.PurchaseDate <= @ToDate)
        OR
        --If @FromDate is not NULL AND @ToDate IS NULL then also check PurchaseDate to be greater than @FromDate
        (@FromDate IS NOT NULL AND @ToDate IS NULL 
         AND Clients.PurchaseDate >= @FromDate)
        OR
        --If @FromDate is NULL AND @ToDate IS NOT NULL then also check Trans_Date to be less than @ToDate 
        (@FromDate IS NULL AND @ToDate IS NOT NULL 
         AND Clients.PurchaseDate <= @ToDate)
END
```

When I execute this stored procedure with NULL parameters, no records are returned.

Any idea where I did go wrong here?

Comment: `(@p IS NULL or col = @p)` for each param.

Comment: @jarlh: For which param ?

Comment: All of them, at least the optional (nullable) ones. Use rel-op according to your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
OR
(@FromDate IS NULL AND @ToDate IS NULL)
```